# National characters in mongo shell can not be used

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

my mongod instance is running on a server with Ubuntu 12.10 (x86_64).

From the mongo shell I'm am not able to perform commands like this:

```
db.listings.update({manName: "Schffer"}, {$set: {manName: "Schäffer"}})
```

The character 'ä' is not possible to be displayed in the mongo shell however in the terminal outside of the mongo shell such chars can be used with no difficulties. More precisely I can not even type the character in mongo shell.

From my Java application national characters can be passed to mongodb in the string values as well and are saved correctly.

I use putty to connect to the server and the Remote character set in Window -> Translation is set to UTF-8.

Do you have some advice how to make mongo shell accept these characters?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: whats your mongodb shell version and what is the output of shell command `locale`

Comment: the version is 2.4.6 and the output following:LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue. As workaround you could type the problem-characters as unicode, e.g. `\u00E4` instead of `ä`.

Comment: ok, thanks, that should be sufficient for now.